# In Category Theory can id be considered an isomorphism?

Tags: category-theory

The definition from isomorphism

> $f$ and $g$ are isomorphisms iff $f.g=id$ and $g.f=id$

Well

$id.id=id$

Does this make $id$ an isomorphism?

My intuition says that not, because that would break the *terminal object* definition, right?

> Terminal object $t$ is a object that has only and only one morphism $f_{t}$ going from any object to it.

I understood that if I have to terminals $t_1$ and $t_2$ there must to be the isomorfisms $f_{t1} : t1 \rightarrow t2$ and $f_{t2} : t2 \rightarrow t1$ and that $f_{t1}.f_{t2}=id_{t1}$

But if I take $id_{t1}$ as an isomorphism, and aslso $f_{t2}$ then there would be two isomorphisms from  *"any object"* to $t1$ and that would break the *unique up to unique isomorphisms* don't?

Or that means that $f_{t1}$, $f_{t2}$, $id_{t1}$, $id_{t2}$ are all the same morphism? (That would make sense for poset)

Comment: That's not the definition of isomorphism; both $fg$ and $gf$ have to be identities.

Comment: Thanks I will edit the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$id$ is an isomorphism, yes.

In your case, you have to be careful about domains and codomains. For instance, $f_{t_2}$ is the unique morphism from $t_2$ to $t_1$, if $t_1$ is terminal.
And similarly, $id_{t_1}$ is the unique morphism from $t_1$ to $t_1$, if $t_1$ is terminal.

Maybe recalling the definition of terminal object can help : $x$ is terminal if and only if, for each $y$ in the category, there is a unique morphism from $y$ to $x$. So, this unique morphism could be written $f_y$, since it depends only on $y$ (assuming $x$ is fixed).

Comment: Hmmmmm, _from y to x_ so in this case the $id$ doesn't count, thanks. So in this case there is only one $f_{y}$. It doesn't matter how many $y$ are there. The diagrams with arrows tricked me, we I see many arrows I think that there are many morphisms, but all they can be the same